# Java how to extract code and then change it?

Tags: java, methods

if I have this in my main method...

String order = "H20" + quantity + price;

then I have another method that would change the quantity of the order.

public static String updateProductionInOrder(String order, String productID, int newQuantity)

In this method I need to change the quantity inside the order, so the order will read the quantity the user wants. But I can't change the parameters or put it in the main method either.

any tips would be appreciated!!!

Comment: You can format your code into code blocks by adding four spaces at the beginning of the line.

Answer (score 1):

**Java Strings are immutable,** so modification of an existing string is not possible.

You have lots of options through. One of the most obvious ones is: **create `Order` class** and use it instead of `String`. The `Order` class would have all the necessary fields (quantity, price, ...), getter and setter methods. You can also define the `toString` method.